# Black Body radiation and Uv, x and gamma rays

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, thermal-radiation

[image: Why is there no uv, xrays or gamma rays???]Is the reason why UV, x-rays and gamma rays are non-existent on the blackbody radiation spectrum is because instead of the atoms present in the walls of the blackbody absorbing the energy, the energy is quite simply "too much" and hence they become ionised instead?
If not the case, what really happens?
What would be the answer to this thought experiment?
A x-ray photon suddenly appears and travels towards a blackbbody cavity. What happens to the x-ray photon, what happens to the atoms of the blackbody cavity inline with the x-ray's trajectory???

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. All wavelengths are present in a true blackbody distribution.

Comment: wait what really? our school textbooks tell us that such energy transitions provided by uv, xrays and gamma rays dont exist in atoms and hence they dont appear on the blackbody spectrum. is this wrong?? please explain for a high school student please???!!! how was the uv catastrophe properly explained then???

Comment: Provide a quote, rather than paraphrasing. A perfect blackbody absorbs *all* radiation incident upon it. How therefore can a blackbody not absorb (and therefore emit, if it is in thermal equilibrium) X-rays. An object that does not emit X-rays *cannot* be a *perfect* blackbody.

Comment: that does make sense. but then why is there no uv, xrays or gamma rays at T=3oooK ??? please explain in laymen terms!!! ASAP!!! thanks rob

Answer (score 0):

I dispute your claim. As you can see from the form of the [Planck function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law), governing the intensity of radiation from a *perfect* blackbody, and from the picture below that plots it, there is radiation at all wavelengths for a blackbody of any temperature. Note the axes have log units and the curves never reach zero.

All that can be said is that there is *very little* X-ray radiation from a blackbody at low temperatures.

I think you are confused between the spectrum of a real object that might approximate a blackbody and the spectrum of a *perfect* blackbody. A *perfect* blackbody absorbs everything incident upon it - including X-rays. Whatever radiative processes cause the absorption of X-rays must also be capable of emitting X-rays. However, a real object may be largely incapable of absorbing or emitting X-rays. Such a thing might have a spectrum that approximates a blackbody at most wavelengths, but it will not be a perfect blackbody.

However, you are describing a cavity. If the cavity absorbs X-rays then that tells you that there *are* radiative processes also capable of emitting X-rays. e.g. If the photons ionise the atoms via the photoelectric effect, then it is also possible for recombination to occur with the emission of X-ray photons. In a true blackbody, these processes will be in perfect equilibrium.

[image: Planck function at various temperatures]

Comment: Ok i see. So this function governs all this. Its only cause of this function that it takes on that shape and by 'chance' its in complete congruence with the experimental data?? is that it? hopefully it is. thank you. by the way rob, can you answer another question of mine??? regarding motors???

Comment: OMG is this a probability curve sorta???? so the probability of high frequency exponentially decays because its just the way the world works and thankfully Planck found some math to describe it precisely and perfectly???? omg that sounds so cool if thats the case